# Mongoose remove object from a Schema arr

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I am trying to remove an array from my model with Mongoose and it dosen't seem to work. I want to delete one object from **`collectionImages`**.  Here is my code:

Schema

```
var CollectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    collectionName: String,
    collectionImages: [
        {
            imageName: String,
        }
    ],
    path: String
});
```

Delete method:

```
router.delete("/collection/:id/:imageId", function (req, res) {
    var imageId = req.params.imageId;

    Collections.findById(req.params.id, function (err, collections) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < collections.collectionImages.length; i++) {
                if (collections.collectionImages[i]._id == imageId) {
                    var checkedImageId = collections.collectionImages[i]._id;
                     collections.collectionImages[i].splice(imageId,1);
                };
            }

        }
        ;
    });
});
```

The form:

```
 <form id="deleteForm" action="/collection/<%= collections._id %>/<%= image._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="post">
                    <button class="fa fa-minus-circle">Delete</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: @ Neil Lunn yes i see it's the same but the solution provided alsow there dosen't work for me. I hope someone with more exprerience can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The following

```
Collections.update(
   { _id: req.params.id },
   { $pull: { 'collectionImages': { '_id': req.params.imageId } } }
).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) { res.status(500).send(err); return; }
    res.send();
});
```

For more read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: Hy @nmanikiran i tried i don't get the 500 error but the object is still there.

Comment: it worked i had to change the router and the _method to PUT. Tanks @nmanikiran